# No success binding an Image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to bind an image on the main window with a string (stored in another class) which represents the file path of the image I want to display.

But nothing shows up.

Here is my main window code xaml code:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="categoryTemplate"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" 
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource animalTemplate}">
        <Grid MouseEnter="DockPanel_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="DockPanel_MouseLeave">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Path=IconFilePath}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16" Height="16" Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" FlowDirection="{Binding Path=FlowDirection}" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Border CornerRadius="2" Background="Lavender" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                <TextBlock Text="30" Foreground="DodgerBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="13" />
            </Border>
            <aea:MenuButton Margin="0,0,2,0" Opacity="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Width="16" Height="16" DisplayStyle="Text" IsEnabled="True" IsDropDownOpen="False">
                <aea:SplitButtonItem IsSelected="True" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Assets\FeedMenu.png" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </aea:SplitButtonItem>
                <aea:SplitButtonItem Tag="{Binding Path=me}" Selected="Subscription_MarkAllAsRead">Mark all as Read</aea:SplitButtonItem>
                <aea:SplitButtonItem Tag="{Binding Path=me}" Selected="Subscription_AddAllToFavorites">Add all to Favorites</aea:SplitButtonItem>
                <aea:SplitButtonItem Tag="{Binding Path=me}" Selected="Subscription_ReadAllLater">Read all Later</aea:SplitButtonItem>
                <aea:SplitButtonItem Tag="{Binding Path=me}" Selected="Subscription_OpenAllBrowser">Open all in browser</aea:SplitButtonItem>
            </aea:MenuButton>
        </Grid>
        
        <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>-->
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Here is my other class:

```
    public string IconFilePath { get; private set; }
    public Subscription()
    {
        this.IconFilePath = @"C:\Users\Din\Din\Programming\Webs\Ended Projects\CodeCaged\Products\Read 360\Read 360\Read 360\bin\Release\feeds\1.ico";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are binding relative to the [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) so you need to make sure its an instance of that class. Also check for [binding errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx), not more to be said with this little context.

Comment: 1. I am already binded to a DataContext and he is correct (I just didn't gave the full code, see the full code), I know it is correct because I am binding to another property on that same class and it is working just find (for example - my TextBlock is binding just fine on the same class) 2. I tried to find binding errors using the guide you gave - nothing came up

Comment: @dinbrca: Are you sure that the path is correct? Can you hard code it as `Source` and it will display the image?

Comment: @dinbrca: Can't think of any reason why it would not work then if the premises are actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard without a full code listing of how this control is setup (e.g. where and how is the DataContext set?, and how is the list of 'Items' populated?)

But on the surface it appears you're expecting to get both 'Name' and 'IconFilePath' from an Items element, so to confirm the Subscription Class defines both IconFilePath and Name?

A tool like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) can automatically display binding errors in a running applications visual tree; and I would expect it to list such in this case.

Also to reduce possible headaches (and this may well be the issue) it may be worth mentioning [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) for your data class. Property **changes** on your data class will not automatically progate otherwise.